# Angular throwing error on my html <ul> tag and as well as my *ng

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm using atom and my ul and  *ngFor is getting an error and I don't understand why. I tried search around but can't seem to find out the reason why I get errors on all *ng stuff as well as my ul. Seems to be html tags aren't appearing.

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'user',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
            <p><strong>Email</strong>: {{email}}</p>
            <p>Address:{{address.street}} {{address.city}}, {{address.state}}</p>
            <button (click) = "toggleHobbies()">Show Hobbies</button>
            <div *ngIf = 'showHobbies'>
            <h3>Hobbies</h3>
              <ul>
                  <li *ngFor="let hobby of hobbies">
                      {{hobby}}
                  </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            `,
})
export class UserComponent  {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  address : address;
  hobbies: string[];
  showHobbies: boolean;


constructor(){
        this.name = 'Richard';
        this.email = 'Rjime061@fiu.edu'
        this.address = {
          street : '12 Main St.',
          city : 'Boston',
          state : 'MA'
        }
    }
        this.hobbies = ['Music', 'Movies', 'Sports'];
        this.showHobbies = false;
}
interface address {
    street: string;
    city: string;
    state: string;
}
```

Comment: Please provide the precise error message you are getting, and any other information about how your app is misbehaving, such as the display in the browser.

Comment: Sure, I just provided my entire code now. I still get the errors on my *ngIf and *ngFor and as well as my ul tag

Comment: Code is good, but please share the error messages. By the way, the lines `this.hobbies =` and `this.showHobbies`--maybe they're supposed to go inside the constructor? Where they are now they would cause a compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

I initially thought that this was somehow caused by [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements):  `Generally, block-level elements may contain inline elements and (sometimes) other block-level elements.` however after trying the code I see that there are two problems, namely:

1. the function **toggleHobbies** is missing
2. there are two variable initialization outside of the constructor

The following code works without issues:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
            <p><strong>Email</strong>: {{email}}</p>
            <p>Address: {{address.street}} {{address.city}}, {{address.state}}</p>
            <button (click) = "toggleHobbies()">Show Hobbies</button>
            <div *ngIf = 'showHobbies'>
            <h3>Hobbies</h3>
              <ul>
                  <li *ngFor="let hobby of hobbies">
                      {{hobby}}
                  </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            `,
})
export class UserComponent {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  address: address;
  hobbies: string[];
  showHobbies: boolean;

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'John Doe';
    this.email = 'jdoe@example.com'
    this.address = {
      street: '12 Main St.',
      city: 'Boston',
      state: 'MA'
    }
    this.hobbies = ['Music', 'Movies', 'Sports'];
    this.showHobbies = false;
  }
  
  public toggleHobbies() {
    this.showHobbies = !this.showHobbies;
  }
}

interface address {
  street: string;
  city: string;
  state: string;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have closed the DIV just before ***ngIf**, which is causing this errors.

Please try following correct version of the code:

```
@Component({
      selector: 'user',
      template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
                <p><strong>Email</strong>: {{email}}</p>
                <p>Address:{{address.street}} {{address.city}}, {{address.state}}</p>
                <button (click) = "toggleHobbies()">Show Hobbies</button>
        <div *ngIf = 'showHobbies'>
        <h3>Hobbies</h3>
          <ul>
              <li *ngFor="let hobby of hobbies">
                  {{hobby}}
              </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        `,
})
```

I have made changes in the line no. 7 of the code.

Comment: Thanks just made that quick fix but I'm still getting error on the what I had mentioned bove about the *ng and ul tag